# After finding if an item is present in a sublist of a list, find if another item is in the same sublist

Tags: python

I have several lists that contain multiple sublists that are structured like this:

```
shape_01 = [['Circle', 'Top'], ['Dot', 'Top']]
```

I have created a function that checks to see if a certain shape item is present and draws that shape.

```
def draw_shape(set):
     if any(('Dot') in i for i in set):
     goto(0,0)  
     dot(25)
```

This draws a dot at 0,0 when the function is entered like this:

```
draw_shape(shape_01)
```

I want to edit the function so it checks to see if 'Top' is present in the same sublist as the shape and then changes from drawing the dot at (0,0) to (0,100).

To sum up in the best terms I can state, how can I check if both 'Dot' and 'Top' are in the same sublist and have the code change accordingly?

Comment: Do you want to check if any sub list of `shape_01` contains both `Dot` and `Top`?

Comment: `'Dot' in i and 'Top' in i`? If you actually want the matched object, `any` doesn't really help you out; use a regular `for` loop.

Comment: @jonrsharpe or even `{'Dot', 'Top'}.issubset(set)`...

Comment: Yes, I would like to check if one sub list contains both dot and top

Comment: Yep, 'Dot' in i and 'Top' in i. How would I go about checking each sub list for those two items and changing the way the code draws those shapes?

Comment: @WhichWayToSanJose are you just going to ignore what's not top and/or not circle? Seems like you want to draw them all - maybe?

Comment: @JonClements I aim to add another if statement underneath to handle looking for that shape.

Comment: @WhichWayToSanJose then you may wish to reconsider your question. As it sounds like you want to draw a certain shape at a certain position as long as some requirements are met... etc... (ie... sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: @JonClements that sounds about right. However, there are some lists I want to draw that do not contain all the shapes (which causes an error if I try to search each sublist for the shape and its attributes), hence why I wanted to use the any statement.

Comment: WhichWayToSanJose `any` will only decide if the entire sequence meets the criteria, not individual elements... you'll still then need to filter those elements... as @jonrsharpe says... a `for` loop seems more appropriate

Comment: @JonClements how would I got about using the for loop to search the list?

Comment: @WhichWayToSanJose For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43452164/6525140

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this. But it should be said that this approach doesn't really scale up if you want to add more attributes, shapes etc.

```
def goto(*pos): print(pos)
def dot(*params): print(params)

def draw_shape(lst):
    for l in lst:
        if 'Dot' in l:
            if 'Top' in l:
                goto(100, 0)
            else:
                goto(0,0)
            dot(25)
```

---

```
def draw_shape(lst):
    for l in lst:
        if 'Dot' in l and 'Top' in l:
            goto(100, 0)
            dot(25)
        elif 'Dot' in l:
            goto(0,0)
            dot(25)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question of how to check if the sublist contains multiple values, i recommend using a function, like this:

```
def any_sublist_contains_all(lists, values_to_find):
    return any(all(value in l for value in values_to_find) for l in lists)
```

It returns True if ALL values in values_to_find are present IN ANY sub_list of lists

so you can do:

```
if any_sublist_contains_all(set, ('Dot','Top')):
    # dot what you want
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the use of sets in python.

```
set(sublist).issuperset(['Top', 'Dot'])
```